# jQuery 18n plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a jQuery i18n plugin init:

```
jQuery.i18n.properties({
    name : 'appsConstants',
    path : '/gadgets/',
    mode : 'both',
    language : 'en'
});
```

How to take out the language variable into browser line like a parameter?

Comment: Do you mean you want the `language` property to be configurable in the URL? e.g. `example.com?language=en`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query string values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @Juhana, but thats parsing parameter, I believe there should be simple setting. Like on JSP: <fmt:setLocale value="${param['locale']}" scope="session"/>

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such thing built into JavaScript. You have to add for example the function in the accepted answer in the duplicate and then do `language: getParameterByName( 'locale' )`.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here:

- Read the language from the URL path or an URL query parameter by parsing `window.location`
- Set the language in a cookie
- Generate your init Javascript dynamically on the server and set the language there (storing it in the session on the server).

Answer (score 0):

This article from Scott Hanselman talks about globalization (cultures/locale)

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

I've used that for making my jQuery aware of the users culture (for use with a datepicker amongst others) I also downloaded the i18n jQuery plugin and registered that.

I went with the "Slightly Less Cheesy - Meta Tag" solution for "detecting" locale and registered a

```
<meta name="accept-language" content="en-US">
```

in the head section, then I could utilize that tag in my jQuery to figure out what locale/language to use.

The article is slightly outdated so some of the javascript needs an update here and there as an example Globalization.js has changed from $.global. to Globalize.
Bits and pieces like that you need to update to get it all working.